# how to send mail without opening default email app on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to send an email without opening the default email app? (directly)
I used two plugins. but both are opened default app.

Using `flutter_email_sender` plugin

```
      final Email email = Email(
        body:
            'Vendor Name = ${value.title} ${value.ownerName}<br>\nCompany Name = ${value.displayName}',
        subject: 'New Vendor Registed',
        recipients: ['sample@gmail.com'],
        isHTML: true,
      );

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email)
```

Using `url_launcher` plugin

```
                     final String _email = 'mailto:' +
                         'bhanukaisuru96@gmail.com'+
                         '?subject=' +
                         'New Vendor Registered' +
                         '&body=' +
                         'Vendor Name =${value.title} ${value.ownerName}\n' +
                         'Company Name = ${value.displayName}';

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send message from flutter app directly using [sendGridApi](https://sendgrid.com/) and http post request .
And Here you need to add sendGridId to your here_your_sendGrid_id.
Here is sample code :

```
  sendRegistrationNotification(String email) async {
Map<String, String> headers = new Map();
headers["Authorization"] =
    "Bearer here_your_sendGrid_id";
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

var url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send';
var response = await http.post(url,
    headers: headers,
    body:
        "{\n          \"personalizations\": [\n            {\n              \"to\": [\n                {\n                  \"email\": \"yourmail@gmail.com\"\n                },\n                {\n                  \"email\": \"yourmail@gmail.com\"\n                }\n              ]\n            }\n          ],\n          \"from\": {\n            \"email\": \"yourmail@gmail.com\"\n          },\n          \"subject\": \"Test Message\",\n          \"content\": [\n            {\n              \"type\": \"text\/plain\",\n              \"value\": \"New user register: $email\"\n            }\n          ]\n        }");
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

}

Comment: This generates an XMLHttpRequest error with Flutter web. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Essentially for security reasons for Flutter Web , you can't make external requests to outside resources within a browser. You may have to create a firebase function to call this API.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can directly Send email from your app via SMTP using **[mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer)** plugin.

*You will need to ask and store user's Email, Password, SMTP port, and host and use these credentials to send emails.*

This will work with pretty much with any email provider.

If you don't want to store user credentials, you would have to individually integrate different Email API's like [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) and Outlook API which use OAuth.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks.. it's working. but need to add email and passord

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a way to do this and finally found it.

https://pub.dev/packages/mailer

Use the mailer plug-in form the link above. It's very simple and easy to use.
Note that you have to add your email as the sender mail and your password so the message will go through, and don't mistake your (sender mail) from the recipient mail.

Comment: I am getting Mailer Exception on some devices but it works fine on some devices, is it because I am using same email for both sender and recipient?