# Send email from custom address in flutter

Tags: flutter, email

I have just started my flutter journey and I am stuck at a point. I want to send emails from my flutter app automatically without opening Gmail. I want to send an email from my client's custom address to any other address.

```
hello@kleenmycar.com
```

Is it possible? If yes kindly help me. If you know of any youtube tutorials, Kindly share them.

Answer (score 1):

I got same question on stack overflow as well also YouTube video. I hope that it will helpful to you.

[Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509092/how-to-send-mail-without-opening-default-email-app-on-flutter)

[Send mail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDwst9icjAY&ab_channel=JohannesMilke)